# Best way to distribute Visual C++ project which also has .net 8.0 dependency

Tags: github, visual-c++, shared-libraries, nuget-package

Hi I have three Visual C++ projects created in Visual Studio 2022, it also has a dependency on .net 8.0, we have a .net code which invokes C++ Dlib library to do certain security operations in Windows operating system.

1. How do i package everything together like Nuget packages or MSI/.exe/cab files?
2. How do i distribute it github, nuget.org, which is the best and easiest and quickest way to distribute such deliverables?